# How can I override a local module in Magento?

Tags: magento

There are many examples of how to override a core module in Magento, but how does one override a local module?

Comment: Just go and edit the code you actually do not need to override local module

Comment: but the module is only overridden in certain circumstances and would like to know if it is possible to override a module in the local code pool.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't override a module, you override (or, more properly, `rewrite`, see below) a class that belongs to a module, or belongs to the general `lib` folder.

Based on your wording, I assume by override you mean "taking a class from `app/code/core/`" and placing it in "`app/code/local/`"?  If that's the case then you mostly can't.  Code pools work because magento adds four paths to the PHP include path.

```
app/code/local
app/code/community
app/code/core
lib
```

Then, when the autoloader says

```
include('Mage/Module/Path/To/File.php');
```

if will first check the `local` folder, then the `community` folder, then the core folder, and finally the `lib` folder.  The `local` folder always wins.

If your class is a Model, Helper, or Block, I'd suggest using the module based rewrite system. The same techniques you use to rewrite classes in the Core modules can be used to rewrite classes in local or community modules.  The point of a module based system is that the code which runs the core system is inserted / behaves the same way as code other people might add to the system.

Comment: Thank you Alan, I feel slightly honoured to get a answer from you after reading and using your layoutViewer module.   This clears things up perfectly.  Good explanation as always!

Comment: What I plan to do is to use a commuinity module but replace one of the models it use.

Comment: Make sure that you read and make use of the last paragraph of Alan's answer. Codepool hackery is not as clean as simply replacing a model via configuration, so that solution is far preferred.

Comment: "The same techniques you use to rewrite classes in the Core modules can be used to rewrite classes in local or community modules. "  --- but how does one rewrite a local module in the local code pool?

Comment: @TommyCoxGreen That question is what brought me to this post. That is all I need to know. Is it possible to override a local module. Before I at least attempt to try.